# What would be the simplest way to alpha sort an array of chars in C?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, character

I'm looking for a simple, easy to understand algorithm to alphabetically sort an array of characters in C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

characters in C have numeric values that happen to be in order, so you just treat your characters like integers.  the C standard library includes a 'qsort' function.  Use that (`man qsort` on a linux-like system).  You might have to convert upper-case letters to lowercase to simplify things, but that's trivial.  If you want to understand the quicksort algorithm (that's the one you should learn, because you'll actually use it), see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort).

Answer (score 2):

Use the qsort method:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int char_compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
  return *(const char *)a - *(const char *)b;
}

int main(){
  const char char_array[] = { 'c', 'a', 'b' };

  qsort (char_array, 3, sizeof(char), char_compare);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the result is intended for humans, it is better to use strcoll. It is slower then strcmp or strcasecmp but it accounts for non-english characters. If you are going to use it don't forget to set your locale for LC_COLLATE, i.e.

setlocale(LC_COLLATE, "");

Answer (score 1):

Just try [Bubble Sort](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Structures/bubble_sort) that's the easiest sorting algorithm.

Comment: Never claim an algorithm is the "slowest" for a particular task.  One can always write a slower one. :)

Comment: Heh indeed, I'll remove the 'slowest'. ;)

Comment: IMHO, insertion sort is easier then bubble sort.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you are really looking for an algorithm or just a way to solve the problem? If the latter, then use [C's qsort](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/qsort/).

If you want an algorith, go for [Insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) or [Selection sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort), as they're very simple to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Easy?  Do a bubble sort.

This is java and int rather than char, but you can easily adapt it...

```
int[] bubble(int a[])
    {
    for (int i = a.length; --i>=0; )
        {
        for (int j = 0; j<i; j++)
            {
            if (a[j] > a[j+1])
                {
                int T = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j+1];
                a[j+1] = T;
                }
            }
        }
    return(a);
    }
```

Comment: surely if you want simple you might as well go for insertion sort or selection sort, rather than bubble sort?

Comment: Thanks but I can't use Java, I should implement the solution in plain C.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple and asymptotically fastest (N is size of array):

```
const unsigned char in[N];
unsigned char out[N], *p=out;
size_t cnt[N]={0}, i, j;
for (i=0; i<COUNT; i++) cnt[in[i]]++;
for (i=0; i<256; i++) for (j=cnt[i]; j; j--) *p++=i;
```